# closure not performing as anticipated

Tags: php, closures

Here's my code:

```
$array = ['foo' => 'bar', 'bis' => 'ter'];
$finalData=[];
$closure = function ($value, $key) use ($finalData) {
    $finalData[]=$value;
};
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $closure($value, $key);
}
var_dump($finalData); // array (0)
```

Why does `$finalData` have `0 elements` inside? Shouldn't it be `['bar','ter']`

Comment: From the [comments on the anonymous functions page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#99287): *"Watch out when 'importing' variables to a closure's scope  -- it's easy to miss / forget that they are actually being copied into the closure's scope, rather than just being made available."*. In other words, `$finalData` inside the function will get a copy of the value that `$finalData` has outside the function *at the moment the function is defined*.

Comment: Instead of doing that, return an array

Answer (score 0):

You merely need to make your `use` variable modifiable by reference:

```
$closure = function ($value, $key) use (&$finalData) {
// add this-----------------------------^
```

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9279b72895dd90cc8b142e25c7b0fb9dfe613b1)